Token gereration to acess Rest API
I want to use cloud foundry rest api to list events, but i need a token int he header. cf oauth-token allows me to get one and test my code, but i see that there is a specific endpoint to get a token (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/version/4.6.0/index.html#overview). I am however a little confused...i am not sure to understand the flow and the necessary input data ... Could anyone help with this please ?
Thanks!
Different endpoints for token generation but none seems to work.
I first tried API flow, by i did not know where to get the client id and the bearer token
Then i tried to call /oauth/token with the  Authorization Code Grant, because it did not need any required input, but at this point i was juste trying out different things to understand how the flow works...
